How can I search for multiple partial keywords in an Excel dynamic search bar?
In Excel I use the following formula and a dynamic search bar (anchored to cell B2) which retrieves information from a data table (two columns, Question and Answer) on a separate sheet (Table1) and shows it below the search bar:
=FILTER(Table1,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$2,Question)),"")
This works fine for single keywords but ideally, I would like to able to input multiple partial keywords into the search bar and any hits would display below.
For example, currently if I search for 'how many people', I get a single result ("How many people are there in the program?") that contains the exact string, but strings containing the words 'how', 'many', and 'people' in different positions are not retrieved ("Many people are wondering how to do it", or "Richard Manyon showed the peoples of the world his idea")

Note: I don't need the text to be highlighted or marked up in any way, just for any retrieved data to show beneath the search bar as it does currently for single keyword input. Additionally, I would like the Answer column to be included in the search (not just the Question column).
Many thanks in advance for anyone that can assist.

So you are using space delimited keywords in your example? Save to say in theory you can split these sentences into seperate words on these spaces?
=FILTER(Table1,BYROW(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TEXTSPLIT(B2," "),Question)),AND))

Without ETA-Lambda:
=FILTER(Table1,BYROW(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TEXTSPLIT(B2," "),Question)),LAMBDA(_row,AND(_row))))


Thank you CODERdotEXE and JvdV for your fast responses. Unfortunately, neither formula seems to work (CODERdotEXE's gives a #VALUE? error and JvdV's gives a #NAME? error). To clarify, I am typing in the search bar (linked to cell B2) and the results beneath appear if and when the keyword matches any entries in the Question column. Additionally, apologies - I have realized that it would be best for any hits to be retrieved from either the Question column OR the Answer column

Thank you JvdV that works a lot better! However, it doesn't seem to narrow down the choices - from what I can see, searching for two keywords separated by a space causes many more (non-relevant) results to appear below (perhaps the space is triggering this somehow). Is it possible to adjust this code so that only the keywords and not the space between are counted?

Hey @Luke, I think the #VALUE? error that you are getting using the formula in my answer is because SUMPRODUCT and FILTERXML may not work as expected when directly combined this way, especially with an array of results from SEARCH. Instead of using SUMPRODUCT directly, we can use BYROW and LAMBDA to evaluate each row properly. Here’s a revised formula: =FILTER(Table1, BYROW(Table1, LAMBDA(row, SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE($B$2, " ", "</s><s>") & "</s></t>", "//s")), row))) > 0)), "")

Try this @Luke if still there is an error...then I think I have a different approach to the problem

@Luke, the answer is ammended. Also, please keep communication with regards to the other answer within the comment section of said answer.

Hi @JvdV - thank you for getting back to me. I've tried the updated 'Without ETA-Lambda' formula and it appears to work perfectly for the Question column - thank you so much! The final piece of the puzzle is to be able to get results from the Answer column as well - could you let me know how this could be done?

@Luke, perfect. Then please accept the answer as such by clicking the check-button next to it just so the thread can be closed. Also remove all these unneeded comments underneath the answer. Any message for CODERdotEXE can be written underneath his answer.

@JvdV I made an edit to the last comment (in keeping with the initial question) - is there a way to include the Answer column in the search so that both Question and Answer data is being retrieved?

@Luke I don't know what you mean. You retrieve the entire table (columns Question & Answer in your example) based on a search for words in the Question column. What has changed?

@JvdV apologies for not being clear - it may be occasionally necessary to search for words that only appear in the Answer column, so I would like the search to be for words in either the Question column or the Answer column. Currently the formula will indeed retrieve the entire table but the keywords are only searching the Question column, (for example, using the example from the image above, if I search for 'How many' the relevant data is retrieved because this text appears in the Question column, but if I search for 'count' it does not, because this text appears in the corresponding answer).

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Thank you @JvdV - I've replied in chat

hi again @JvdV - I haven't heard back from you in a few days so I'm going to go ahead and proceed with the above version of the formula (this will suffice for our purposes). Many thanks for your excellent work!

@Luke, sorry I've totally forgot. I'll reply in chat

Assuming the search bar is in B2 and the data table is named Table1use this formula:
=FILTER(Table1, BYROW(Table1, LAMBDA(row, 
    SUM(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TEXTSPLIT($B$2, " "), INDEX(row, , 1)))) > 0 
    OR 
    SUM(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TEXTSPLIT($B$2, " "), INDEX(row, , 2)))) > 0
)), "")


We can breakdown this formula , where:
TEXTSPLIT takes whatever is in B2, and it splits that into individual keywords based on spaces. INDEX(row,,1) refers to whatever is in the column for the Question in the current row. INDEX(row,,2) refers to whatever is in the column for the Answer in the current row. SEARCH Confirms the presence of every keyword in those columns. ISNUMBER  Converts the result of the SEARCH to TRUE/FALSE. --ISNUMBER Converts TRUE/FALSE to 1/0. SUM Adds up the 1s and 0s. BYROW Applies that filtering logic to each row of Table1. LAMBDA function that checks for the presence of any of the keywords in either column of the row.
Note
Use OR if you want to include rows where any of the keywords appear in either column.
Use AND if you want to include rows where all the keywords must appear in either column.

Hey, you may want to test this with multiple rows in Table1. SUMPRODUCT returns a single value, in FILTER sizes need to match; also here converting to number is needed for ISNUMBER, for example with --ISNUMBER. BTW, FILTERXML is not available under Mac or Web versions.

Yeah you are right... we need a boolean array that matches the number of rows in Table1, not a single value.

I think we can use TEXTSPLIT , BYROW and LAMBDA to apply the filter logic.... so i am updating the answer based on this ...

Good, I'm posting one shortly :)

hi all - many thanks. CODERdotEXE: i've tried adding your latest formula but it's giving an error ("There is a problem with this formula. Not trying to post a formula? ...") I also tried your earlier SUMPRODUCT formula - this doesn't give an error but it doesn't generate any results either
